# What is the difference between PDIP and MDIP?

Tags: dip

What is the difference between these opamps?

MDIP: http://dk.rs-online.com/web/p/komparatorer/5338186/

PDIP: http://dk.rs-online.com/web/p/komparatorer/0428458/

PDIP: http://dk.rs-online.com/web/p/komparatorer/7140789/

I need an LM311 which I can use on bread board as a comparator with fast switching. Some has MDIP some PDIP. What is the difference? ?Are all these the same except their switching times and voltage ranges? Will they be treated the same way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opamp is the same, it is only the packaging which is (slightly) different:

PDIP = Plastic Dual-In-line Package

MDIP = Molded Dual-In-Line Package

Since both are DIP (Dual-In-line Package) you can use them on a breadboard.
The difference between Plastic and Molded is completely irrelevant for you !
Just get the cheapest.

The silicon circuit inside is IDENTICAL (assuming they are from the same manufacturer).

So switching times and voltage ranges are also IDENTICAL.

Comment: the weird thing is that MDIP has longer response time but it is more expensive

Comment: Sometimes a technically inferior product can be more expensive when there is little demand for it. So more expensive certainly does not mean that it is better. If you want cheap, look on Ebay for these opamps !

Comment: The difference in response time can also depend on the manufacturer. For exact data, look at the manufacturer's datasheet. The logo of the manufacturer should be printed on the IC package. But don't worry, you probably cannot even measure this difference in response time unless you have a very fast oscilloscope.

Answer (score 8):

The LM311 was invented, if memory serves, by National Semiconductor, as were most parts beginning with 'LM'. Since it was introduced (perhaps in the 1970s) it has been second-sourced by other manufacturers including Motorola (now On Semi) and Texas Instruments. In some cases the specifications may be somewhat different, and the packaging will vary by manufacturer and, over time, even within a given manufacturer's line as they make changes.

In 2011, Texas Instruments purchased National Semiconductor and folded the line into their own, updating the data sheets over the next couple of years to elide the National Semiconductor name and replace it with their own.

[image]

In this case, the LM311N/NOPB was the National Semiconductor part (the NOPB was added when lead was eliminated), and LM311P was the TI part. Now they are both TI parts, but they are almost surely made in different facilities and have slightly different specifications. The packages also have slight differences in the plating, and the plastic shipping tubes are different sizes (40 vs. 50 to a tube) etc.

[image]

[image]

Also, the TI LM311P [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm211.pdf), as of right now, has a rather glaring error- referring to the part as a quad!

[image]

Bottom line, as a hobbyist-user, it makes no difference to you. **Pick whichever you like**- just as if they were from two different manufacturers. Possibly at some time in the future one of them will be obsoleted- chances are it will be the one that costs more since they are discouraging use of it. PDIP and MDIP are just names used by the two companies before the purchase- to refer to very similar things.

To a real manufacturer, they are most certainly **not** the same, and purchasing department may require special dispensation to be able to substitute one for the other, or it may be prohibited in some cases where the substitute has not been qualified or has been found to cause problems. The packages are different as are the chips inside.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the package. PDIP = Plastic Dual Inline Package, [MDIP](http://www.icpackage.org/MDIP/) = Moulded Dual Inline Package.

In practice, they are the usually the same; electronics is littered with multiple acronyms and descriptions for the same thing.

Comment: the weird thing is that MDIP has longer response time but it is more expensive

Answer (score 0):

There is also another difference in the summary specifications, the voltage range is 5-28v, or 9-28v.

Never trust a summary spec, especially typical figures in it, without going back to the data sheet and seeing what measurement conditions are being imposed.

You may find that if a part is intended for a military or higher performance market, specifications may be quoted over a wider range of temperatures, or supply voltages, or for heavier capacitive loading on the output. In the good old days, 50pF was frequently used as an output load, though these days much lower might be quoted. Little differences like this can change the specs.